# How do I make a Gtk.Frame's label bold?

Tags: c#, gtk, gtk#

Usually, for Labels you can do something like this:

```
Label label = new Label ("<b>Some Text</b>") {
    UseMarkup = true
};
```

However, Gtk.Frame's label is just a string, not a full-fledged Label. I can't find an option to use markup. How to I enable markup, or otherwise set the label to be bold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The label of a GtkFrame [can be any widget](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/GtkFrame.html#gtk-frame-set-label-widget) and you can use your own GtkLabel if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

**Gtk.Frame** has the possibility of setting any widget as "label". You can access this widget by accessing the property *LabelWidget*. Using this possibility, you can set a new **Gtk.Label** with any properties you need.

```
var frmExample = new Gtk.Frame();
frmExample.LabelWidget = new Gtk.Label() { Markup = "<b>Example</b>" };
this.Add( frmExample );
this.showAll();
```

The solution is actually simpler for the specific case of a label with markup. I've found that the **Gtk.Frame** already has a **Gtk.Label** attached, and, as you said, you can set the *markup* property to *true*.

```
var frmExample = new Gtk.Frame( "<b>Example</b>" );
( (Gtk.Label) this.frmExample.LabelWidget ).UseMarkup = true;
this.Add( frmExample );
this.showAll();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Following your friendly style: False. The code works since I have used it tons of times. Obviously you don't know about Gtk# since you are referring to the underlying (core) Gtk+ library. Take into account that Gtk# could add behaviour or state you don't know about: a good reason for prudence. Specially in such a questionable phrase like: "If you had tested this code, you'd know it won't work."

Comment: +1; I learned something new from all this :-) I'll need to check whether `gtkmm` also has a default `Label` widget, which could be very useful! I thought it just had a string but, as you noted, might've been wrongly extrapolating from GTK+, or maybe I didn't even read _that_ right ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how it would look in C# but in plain C you could do this:

```html
  frame = GTK_WIDGET (g_object_new (GTK_TYPE_FRAME, "label", "", NULL));
  label = gtk_label_new(_("<b>Scope</b>"));
  gtk_label_set_use_markup(GTK_LABEL(label), TRUE);
  gtk_frame_set_label_widget (GTK_FRAME(frame), label);
```